# GitHub for Windows can not sync to repo while command line tools can

Tags: windows-8, git, github

I have my git repos hosted on a server using [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html). I can access them using SSH like this and it works from Mac OS X/Linux:

```
git clone git@example.net
```

On a Windows 8 Box I now have installed [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com) (GH4W) to access these Repos. I have set up the SSH keys and everything works from the Git-Shell (Powershell):

```
C:\Users\joni\Documents\GitHub> git clone git@example.net:testing
Cloning into 'testing'...
Warning: Permanently added 'example.net,13.37.42.42' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 114, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
remote: Total 114 (delta 29), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (114/114), 9.72 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
C:\Users\joni\Documents\GitHub>
```

When I add this repo to GitHub for Windows now per drag and drop, GitHub for Windows  cannot sync. I can do local commits and the remote is listed unter `Settings > Primary remote (Origin)`, but the `sync` button never appears when I did local commits, and I also cannot pull changes from the server.

However everything works if I just open a shell in the repo (`Tools > Open a Shell here`) and do a `git pull` or `git push` manually.

So this must be an issue with GitHub for Windows ?

Comment: Look like it related problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644888/how-to-push-with-git-to-github-on-windows

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably should be reported at GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

This IS NOT a github issue but a user error.

Joni create and use a github application token use that the first time and maintain it like any other ssh key (as the token is an ssh key slaved to the u/n and application )